# Force react component to only accept a child with a specific type

Tags: reactjs

I have this following component:

```
interface InputWithButtonProps {
  label: string;
  children: React.ReactElement<typeof CustomButton>;
}

const InputWithButton = ({
  label,
  fieldName,
  disabled,
  children,
}: InputWithButtonProps): JSX.Element => {

  return (
     <>
      <TextField label={label} />
      {Children.only(children)}
     </>
  );
};


export default InputWithButton;
```

And the code for CustomButton is:

```
export declare const CustomButton: import("@material-ui/core").ExtendButtonBase<import("@material-ui/core").ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>;
```

What I want from `InputWithButton` is to only accept one single child of type CustomButton, but specifying the type using `React.ReactElement<typeof CustomButton>` doesn't do any checks, so the following code will work just fine (Which should throw an error in this case):

```
<InputWithButton label="some label">
  <div>test</div>
</InputWithButton>
```

The `InputWithButton` should only accept this:

```
<InputWithButton label="some label">
  <Button>Some button</Button>
</InputWithButton>
```

I also tried to specify the children type as following:

```
children: React.ReactElement<ButtonProps>;
```

Which didn't work either.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the condition that checks if the children's type is Button or not, consider the code below that will solve your problem if I understand your problem correctly,

```
interface InputWithButtonProps {
  label: string;
  children: React.ReactElement<typeof CustomButton>;
}

const InputWithButton = ({
  label,
  fieldName,
  disabled,
  children,
}: InputWithButtonProps): JSX.Element => {
  return typeof children.type == 'function' && 
  children.type.name == "Button" && 
  (
     <>
      <input label={label} />
      {children}
     </>
  );
};


export default InputWithButton;
```

The component will return nothing if the tag is other than 'Button', you can remove the 'typeof children.type' condition because it only checks if the children is custom made component or an HTML tag.